# How to color stage to green if it was successful on the second retry?

Tags: jenkins, workflow, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I faced a problem during building my pipeline job.
I have some stages and one of them contains "retry" block. Something like this:

```
stage "1"
stage "other job call"
node{
    def job
    retry(3)
        {
            job = build job: 'Called job', parameters:
                        [
                            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'Branch', value: "Branch"],
                        ];
        }
    }
}

stage "2"
```

So, another job is called and it is successfully built from the second time. But the stage is colored to red, despite it was successful:
[image]

[image]

How to color this stage to green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you, I was looking for the possibility to change the state or colour of one stage and finally it seems that we don’t have access to this functionality (maybe if you create your own plugin…)

Anyway, in your case the function “[Retry](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#retry-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times)” allow to retry the block (up to N times) if any exception happens during its body execution. Then if you use retry function you will automatically get this stage state.

I don’t really understand why you use "retry", but if you want to avoid this behaviour try to use some other functionality like:

- [try/catch/finally](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_exception_handling.htm) blocks
- [catchError](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/CatchErrorStep/help.html) block
- currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'     // 'SUCCESS' | 'FAILURE' | 'UNSTABLE'
- sleep     // if you need to wait for something else

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to change the status of a single stage (without changing the whole build status)?

Comment: @OlivierTerrien Have you found a solution for this?